# rails html helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partials

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to generate a bit of html AND nest content inside it.  Using HAML. Basically I want to do something like:

```
= block_large
  This is some nested content
```

And that should generate:

```
<div class="block large">
  <img src="block_large_carat.gif" class="block_large_carat">
  This is some nested content
</div>
```

The problem is I don't know how to go about achieving this.  Partials?  Helper?  I'm getting hung up on how I would nest whatever content I want.  Trying to keep my HAML DRY and don't want to have to explicitly declare the image tag over and over again.

Comment: Partials make sense as the way to go.

Comment: Ok, but how do you nest content inside a partial?  Rails noob here =P

Comment: You can't pass blocks to partials. A helper is the better option. But I haven't time to post an example now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited:
My previous solution didn't work :)
Thanks EmFi for pointing it out.
This time I (even) tested it and it (even) worked! \o/

I'm posting this here based on [this blog post](http://www.igvita.com/2007/03/15/block-helpers-and-dry-views-in-rails/).
Read the full post for a much better explanation :)

#### app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
  def block_to_partial(partial_name, options = {}, &block)
    options.merge!(:body => capture(&block))
    concat(render(:partial => partial_name, :locals => options), block.binding)
  end
```

#### app/views/xxx/new.html.haml

```
%h2 Test!
- block_to_partial("block_large", :class_name=>"nested_content") do
  This is some nested content
OOps..
```

#### app/views/xxx/_block_large.html.haml

```
#block_large
  %img(src="block_large_carat.gif" class="block_large_carat")
  %div(class=class_name)
    = body
```

### Renders:

```
<div id='block_large'>
  <img class='block_large_carat' src='block_large_carat.gif' />
  <div class='nested_content'>
    This is some nested content
  </div>
</div>
OOps..
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No good. The block given to render is only processed with render :update.

Comment: True. (shame on me) Fixing it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I still haven't had a chance to try this out but it makes sense :)